# chromeOS/chromebook VScode File saving

Tags: file, google-chrome, visual-studio-code, operating-system, google-chrome-os

I save files on VScode, but I cant find a way to save it to regular files on the chromeOS

I have tried searching through all of the files, creating new folders, etc.
And nothing has worked to properly save it to anywhere.

Comment: what's happening when you try to save? Do you have the menu option to save under the "File" menu?

Comment: It can only access My files > Linux files by default.

Comment: I had to use terminal to install it, but  the saving has acess to more complex file saving, even the ability to mod the computer...
which I am not doing, but I found the problem, you just have to save the files to desktop

Comment: you can't save to anywhere other than Linux files and the desktop?

Comment: @starrball I can, however, the only way I can see it through regular chromeOS files is in desktop, I dont know why